# Unstable homotopy groups of spheres beyond Toda's range

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

In 1962 Toda published his book "Composition methods in homotopy groups of spheres", which contains computations of $\pi_{n+k}(S^n)$ for $k\le 19$ and $n\le 20$. The values of these groups are conveniently tabulated, and reproduced on the Wikipedia page [Homotopy groups of spheres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_groups_of_spheres). The computations involve composition product, Toda brackets and the EHP sequence, as well as cohomology operations for the higher values of $k$.

I am fairly certain that more values of $\pi_{n+k}(S^n)$ have been computed in the intervening years, perhaps with more modern methods such as the unstable Adams spectral sequence.

> Does anybody know of an up-to-date table of known unstable homotopy groups of spheres, beyond the range shown in Toda's tables?

Comment: Mark Behrens used the Goodwillie tower and the EHP sequence to reproduce calculations in the Toda range.  http://arxiv.org/abs/1009.1125

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't know the answer to your question, but I asked Fred Cohen.  He had this to say:

Most of the computations are in Mahowald's work
with the EHP sequence. This gives infinite
families at p = 2 with Rob Thompson's  extensions to p > 2.

Specific extensions of 2-primary components in fixed stems
are in

- N. Oda, On the 2-components of the unstable homotopy groups of spheres. II, Proc. Japan Acad. 53, Ser. A(1977), 215-218.
- N. Oda, Unstable homotopy groups of spheres, Bull. of the Inst. for Advanced Re-
  search of Fukuoka Univ. 44 (1979), 49-152.
- N. Oda, Some relations in the 18-stem of the homotopy groups of spheres, Bull.
  Central Res. Inst. Fukuoka Univ., 104, (1988), 75–83. ​

Brayton Gray gave families of elements of order $p^r$ in
$\pi_*(S^{2r+1})$ for $p$ an odd prime.

Example: It is not known whether there are elements of order 64 in $\pi_*(S^{11})$.

Similarly, it is not known whether there are elements of order 64 in the stable
homotopy of $\mathbb RP^{10}$, thus a potential counterexample to the Freyd conjecture.

Other than that, not much more in terms of specific computations
are in the literature as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks, Ryan. This seems fairly definitive. I'll take a look at these references, and if nobody tells me that the results have been handily tabulated I'll accept this answer.

Comment: Does anybody have a reference for Rob Thompson’s extensions?

Answer (score 19):

By following Ryan's leads I've been able to find references computing $\pi_{n+k}(S^n)$ for $20\leq k \leq 30$ at the prime $2$ (and in some cases at odd primes as well). I thought I'd post these as an answer for ease of reference.

- M. Mimura, H. Toda, *The (n+20)-th homotopy groups of n-spheres*, J. Math. Kyoto Univ. 3 1963 37–58. [Contains $\pi_{n+20}(S^n)$ for all $n$ and at all primes]
- M. Mimura, *On the generalized Hopf homomorphism and the higher composition*,
  Parts I, II. J. Math. Kyoto Univ., 4, 171-190, 301-326 (1964/5). [Contains $\pi_{n+21}(S^n)$ and $\pi_{n+22}(S^n)$ for all $n$ and at all primes. For odd primes the author refers to work of Toda later published as a series of papers *On iterated suspensions I--IV*, J. Math. Kyoto Univ (1966/68).]
- M. Mimura, M. Mori, N. Oda, *Determination of 2-components of the 23- and 24-stems in homotopy groups of spheres*, Mem. Fac. Sci. Kyushu Univ. Ser. A 29 (1975), no. 1, 1–42. [Contains $\pi_{n+23}(S^n)$ and $\pi_{n+24}(S^n)$ for all $n$ at the prime $2$]
- N. Oda, *On the 2-components of the unstable homotopy groups of spheres* Parts I, II, Proc. Japan Acad. 53, Ser. A(1977), no. 6/7, 202-205/215-218. [Contains $\pi_{n+k}(S^n)$ for $25\leq k\leq 30$ for all $n$ at the prime $2$, and partial results for $31\leq k\leq 33$]

The methods are as in Toda's book. I would be interested to learn of any later references, or errata to the above.

Comment: see also the answers in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/159471/cokernel-of-the-stable-j-homomorphism-at-odd-primes.